# Java logging - append a string to previous log message

Tags: java, logging, append, line

I'm using `java.util.logging` for logging many file operations (like copy, delete, move, mkdir). Beneath is an example copy job:

```
try {
    LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Copying Binary [ {0} ] to SDCard folder [ {1} ]", new Object[]{src, dst});
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(src, dst);
    // append "..Ok" to previous log message
} 
catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "FileNotFoundException: Binary ["+ src.getAbsolutePath() + "] is missing");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "IOException: Binary [" + src.getAbsolutePath() + "] is unaccessible");
}
```

Is it possible to append the text `..Ok` to the previous log message? 
So the output would say:

```
FINE: Copying Binary [ C:\dir\sub\a.bin ] to SDCard [   Y:\SDCard ]  ..OK
```

Comment: Logging output is non-deterministic. You should definitely not really on a guaranteed output order of your log messages, especially in a multi threaded environment.

Answer (score 1):

no, you can't adorns to an log record. you can however build a string and only log it when you are done.